# Unittest class attribute error

Tags: unit-testing, pyserial

the unittestcase class is returning the error that 
AttributeError: 'M2McommTestMethods' object has no attribute 'ser'
while running the following code.Pleas explain why this happens

import unittest
import serial
import math
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import random
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/vasudev/M2Mtesting')
import espmasterdriver as em

class M2McommTestMethods(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUP(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    print(self.ser.name)
    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.flushOutput()

def test_config(self):
    comm1 = "<CONFIG "
    self.ser.write(bytes(comm1, "utf-8"))
    arr = em.arraygen()
    for k in arr:
        if k not in range(0, 256):
            t = em.ToArray(k)
            self.ser.write(bytes(t))
    else:
        self.ser.write(bytes(k))
    comm2 = ">"
    self.ser.write(bytes(comm2, "utf-8"))
    data_raw = self.ser.readline()
    resp1 = b'ACK\r\n'
    self.AssertEqual(data_raw, resp1, "Not Equal")

def tearDown(self):
    self.ser.close()
```

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(M2McommTestMethods)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

Comment: Sorry......I am new to using unittest and pyserial libraries...I ran a similar code for a smaller test firmware in arduino and it was working perfectly....The setUP method was exactly same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You need a betted description in the question.

Comment: I am trying to send some bits over serial port and get the reponse fromthe controller running a firmware and testing to see if the response is as expected

Comment: The first part of test_config method is actually for packet generation